# How do I extend a 3Ds Max material correctly

Tags: scripting, 3dsmax, maxscript, 3ds

Basically, I'm just trying to add a few more properties to the "Standard" material in 3Ds Max 9. I've actually managed to accomplish this through max script, but it is breaking our exporter.

The exporter works fine for anything skinned with the normal "Standard" material, but the extended version seems to hide the base class's properties from the exporter.

What I have so far is this:

```
plugin material Standard_WithOutlines
name:"Standard & Outlines"
classID:#(0x73212413, 0x1ca9e3e6)
extends:Standard replaceUI:false version:1
(
    parameters shaderParameters
    (
        diffuse type:#color
        glossiness type:#float
        specular type:#color
        specularLevel type:#float
        selfIllumColor type:#color
        selfIllumAmount type:#float
        opacity type:#float

        on diffuse get val do delegate.diffuse
        on glossiness get val do delegate.glossiness / 100.0
        on specular get val do delegate.specular
        on specularLevel get val do delegate.specularLevel
        on selfIllumColor get val do delegate.selfIllumColor
        on selfIllumAmount get val do delegate.selfIllumAmount
        on opacity get val do delegate.opacity / 100.0

        on diffuse set val do delegate.diffuse = val
        on glossiness set val do delegate.glossiness = val * 100.0
        on specular set val do delegate.specular = val
        on specularLevel set val do delegate.specularLevel = val
        on selfIllumColor set val do delegate.selfIllumColor = val
        on selfIllumAmount set val do delegate.selfIllumAmount = val
        on opacity set val do delegate.opacity = val * 100.0
    )

    parameters MainParams rollout:ExtendedMatRollout
    (
        ShowOutlining type:#boolean animatable:false default:false ui:outline_Enabled
        OutlineColour type:#color animatable:false default:(color 0 0 0) ui:outline_Colour
        OutlineThickness type:#float animatable:false default:5 ui:outline_Thickness
    )

    rollout ExtendedMatRollout "Extended Parameters"
    (
        groupBox outlinegrp "Outlining" pos:[8,0] width:312 height:62
        checkbox outline_Enabled "Enabled" pos:[18,16] width:128 height:16
        colorPicker outline_Colour "Colour:" pos:[160,34] width:56 height:20 enabled:ShowOutlining
        spinner outline_Thickness "Thickness:" pos:[50,36] width:80 height:16 enabled:ShowOutlining range:[0,100,0]
        on outline_Enabled changed state do
        (
            outline_Colour.enabled = state
            outline_Thickness.enabled = state
        )

    )
)
```

By declaring the variables myself, the exporter could read them, but this didn't actually link to the values being set by the UI. To solve that, I used the 'on XXX get/set' events to link to the hidden items. So those now work correctly, but the material maps for things like diffuse and specular don't work (which is the only way to texture the thing AFAIK).

How should I be going about adding these couple of settings to a material type, so that it exports all of the data within the 'delegate' class as well (is basic inheritance too much to ask for)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two possiblities:

1. Does your exporter enumerate all the paramblocks?  I imagine that your parameters in the script will end up in an additional pblock.  If your exporter just looks at pblock 0 that might be your problem.
2. I haven't seen this usage before where parameters have the same name in the script and the delegate.  I think you typically are supposed to make new parameters in the script and assign to the delegate ones appropriately, using different names.  At least, that's how I've done it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic extended shader.
I think the problem you have is that your rollout is not specified for the parameters.
If it's not defined, then you cannot find then, if it cannot find them then exporter get's all buggy.

```
plugin material Matte name:"Matte" classID:#(0x61108483, 0x4d218a72) extends:Standard replaceUI:true version:1
( 
    parameters main rollout:params
    (
        kdColor type:#color default:[90,90,90] ui:mkdColor
        on kdColor set val do delegate.diffuse_color = val
    )

    rollout params "Matte Parameters"
    (
        -- Basic matte parameters
        group "Basic Parameters" (
            colorpicker mkdColor "Diffuse: " across:2
        )

    )
)
```